Is there a systematic way to construct the parity and charge conjugation operator for any Poincaré irreducible representation?
I am currently taking an undergraduate introductory QFT course. However, the proceeding will be about classical field theory, the results of which I assume will carry over mutatis mutandis into quantum field theory (if they do not carry over in a natural way, then I would appreciate clarification on how it does not).
We introduced the parity and change conjugation transformations for scalar, vector, and bispinor fields. However, we did so in an ad hoc manner, i.e., we constructed what "worked". Based on this sample of three irreps, it seems that these transformations will in general take different forms for different (finite dimensional) Poincaré irreducible representations.
So, my question is: is there a systematic way to construct the parity and charge conjugation transformations for a given (finite dimensional) Poincaré irrecudible representation?

The irreducible representations of the Poincare Lie algebra, generated by the four 4  tangent $\partial_i$, the 2 generators of rotation $L_{ik}$ in the 2 cartesian planes plus their Lie product, and one boost $K_{t,x}$  together with its Lie product with the rotation subalgebra, does not contain reflections, time inversions or charge conjugations.
You have to use direct products of isomorphic groups in order to introduce flips between factors for time and space inversion.
You have to introduce complex representions with the adjunction of a $U(1)$ gauge group freedom, that allows to change the sign of the imaginary field term in the translation operator, that replaces the standard taylor sum$$T_a f(x) =e^{a \partial_x}\ f(x) = f(e^{a (\partial_x )} x )=f(x+a)$$  by $$T_a f(x) = e^{a (\partial_x + i A(x))}f( x )$$
The celebrated CPT-theorem states, that the product of these three sign changes can be represented by an operator in any Poincarè-invariant field theory, even if e.g. the parity operator is abesent.
Most of the linear representation theory of the Lorentz group was developed by Gelfand and Naimark
